# Joining data from different lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

Let's create some sample data

```
Clear["Global`*"];

data1 = {{1, 0.2}, {3, 1.2}, {5, -0.4}};
data2 = {{2, -0.9}, {4, -0.1}, {6, 0.3}};

L1 = ListPlot[data1, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.012]}];
L2 = ListPlot[data2, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.012]}];

plot = Show[{L1, L2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

My question is the following: how can I connect with straight lines (in black color) all the data (from both lists), starting from that with the lowest value of $x$, up to the one with the largest value of $x$ coordinate?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data3  = SortBy[Join[data1, data2], First]; 

Show[ListPlot[data3, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Black], L1, L2]
```

or

```
ListPlot[data3, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Black,  Epilog -> {L1[[1]], L2[[1]]}]
```

or

```
ListPlot[{data1, data2, data3}, Joined -> {False, False, True},
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, PointSize[0.012]],
    Directive[Red, PointSize[0.012]], Directive[Black, PointSize[0]]}]
```

all give

[image]

Alternatively, using `Mesh`:

```
ListPlot[data3, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Black, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
  Mesh -> {Join[Thread[{data1[[All, 1]], Blue}], Thread[{data2[[All, 1]], Red}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: II want the points to have the original color (red and blue); not all of them with the same color.

Answer (score 6):

```
ListLinePlot[SortBy[Join[data1, data2], First], PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Update:

```
data = SortBy[Join[data1, data2], First];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], {Blue, Point[data1]}, {Red, Point[data2]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! But if I want also the points on the same diagram?

Comment: II want the points to have the original color (red and blue); not all of them with the same color.

Answer (score 1):

You may do the following as well:

```
 ss = Riffle[data1, data2]

 ListLinePlot[ss,Mesh -> Full]
```

Comment: But if I want also the points on the same diagram?

Comment: Just add the option Mesh->Full

Comment: II want the points to have the original color (red and blue); not all of them with the same color.